# React hook form v7 issue while deploying a next js app on vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, vercel, chakra-ui

I'm building a web app with nextjs and chakra UI using typescript. I use react hook form for form validation but it is causing an issue while I deploy it on vercel. Look at the image to see the error message.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: This looks like a TypeScript error. This should throw an error locally, regardless of where you deploy, when you run `next build`. If you remove that typing, does it work?

Comment: Getting the same error, how did you go about it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using next.js and deploying to vercel and had this error just now, read around and found out that if you use RHF v7, you should have  TS 4.1 and above, I upgraded typescript to latest and the error is gone.